# Sharing links posted to a wall via an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, sharing

I've created an app which enables business to post links to their Facebook wall as the business (have proper business auth tokens, etc.).

However the links posted via the app do not have a *share* link, only *comments* and *like*. When a link is posted through the Facebook UI to the business wall it does contain a *share* link along with *comments* and *like*.

What am I missing to enable the link posted via my app to have a *share* link?

I am currently issuing a POST request to the following URL to create the posts:

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/[profileId]/feed?message=[message]&link=[link]&...
```

Comment: I also have the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a reported bug and have not been fixed yet. have a look (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/307556529334653)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need publish_stream permission for that and publish what they write. IMO Facebooks makes difference between feed and stream. Just my thoughts :)

Comment: I am requesting _publish_stream_ and _offline_access_ and am able to post to the businesses wall as the business from my app, except the posts don't have a share link. Is it possible to create a URL to post to the stream similar to [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/streamPublish)? In this case would the post have a _share_ link?

Answer (score 0):

that's the standard procedure when you have a user post via app. I don't think there's a way to have users post as themselves, as far as links are concerned. What you can do is have them post a status update and that one will be seen as posted by the user (no app information). 
There's no other procedure I am aware of that can do that. I hope this helps